# Transition Js animation loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, transition

I am using transit.js for a certain experiment.

I am trying to make a square to go for an infinite animation of **moving to the right while flipping itself.**
But using a loop, the square only flips once,and the rest of the time it just moves to the right. Any suggestion?

```
<body>
<div id="square" style="width:200px;height:200px;transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(180deg);">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0b1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0b1.js"></script>
<script src="js/transition.js"></script>
<script>
var animating = false;
transit();
function transit(){
if (!animating)
{
    animating = true;
    $('#square').transition({
          perspective: '500px',
          x: '+=50',
            rotateX: 180,
            rotateY: 180
    },'slow',function (){animating = false; });
     window.setTimeout(function() { transit() }, 1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the square rotated 180 deg, every iteration set it as 180 deg, which is it's current rotation value hense no animation.. Incrementing up the way you do with the x-axis will rotate every iteration. IE `rotateX: '+=180'`

http://jsfiddle.net/75p76esy/1/

```
$('#square').transition({
    perspective: '500px',
    x: '+=50',
    rotateX: '+=180',
    rotateY: '+=180'
};
```